# How to give "Infinity" as width in Windows 10 for wpf controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I recently updated to Windows 10. I am getting error with controls where width is specified as Infinity.
Below is my code:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" MaxWidth="500" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button ............./>

    </StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <bases:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=control1, Path=Visibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel1}" PropertyName="MaxWidth" Value="500"/>                        
                        </bases:DataTrigger>
                        <bases:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=control1, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel1}" PropertyName="MaxWidth" Value="Infinity"/>                        
                        </bases:DataTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

It was working fine and still works fine in windows 7/8/8.1, I have upgraded to windows 10 and getting error that "Infinity is not a valid value for Double."

Any Idea?

Comment: Is this your application? do you have some code so we can actually help?

Comment: Get a wider monitor? :-)

Comment: @PhilippeParé: Yes, I have added code in question.

Comment: Why do you want infinite width exactly? perhaps there's a better way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2):

I found one alternative:

```
 Value="{x:Static system:Double.PositiveInfinity}"
```

If someone knows anything else please let me know :)